# While going to the sprints or boards I want to see the last comment in the discussion shown for user story

Tags: azure-devops, visible, sprint

We need to see the last comment during stand-up and now we can't see this latest updates

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid we can not see the last comment of the discussion in sprints or boards. If you would like that feature, please [create a request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) for this feature.

By the way, I found a suggestion ticket about [Add the discussion field to the list of available columns for any work item query](http://Add%20the%20discussion%20field%20to%20the%20list%20of%20available%20columns%20for%20any%20work%20item%20query). We can achieve your needs if this suggestion ticket can be took as roadmap. You can vote and track this ticket.